# Is there any difference between declaring @param[in] and @param (without [in]) in C libraries?

Tags: doxygen

Add info to question:

I'm very new writting this kind of descriptions for my functions.

I can't see any difference between declare function variables description in the library (anylib.h) like

```c
#ifndef MYLIB_H
# define MYLIB_H

/**
 * My function description.
 * 
 * @param[in] x Mtrx size x.
 * @param[in] y Mtrx size y.
 * 
 * @return Result.
 */
int *my_function(int x, int y);

#endif
```

(Sorry if image is an url instead image, is because low reputation)

[VSCode showing function description in file.c using @param[in]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvgdb.png)

> or declare like

```c
#ifndef MYLIB_H
# define MYLIB_H

/**
 * My function description.
 * 
 * @param x Mtrx size x.
 * @param y Mtrx size y.
 * 
 * @return Result.
 */
int *my_function(int x, int y);

#endif
```

[VSCode showing function description in file.c using @param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTjzw.png)

> **The library is included with -I ( i ) flag**

```
INC = -I include -I ./mylibdir/ -I ./inc/anotherdir/ 

...

$(OBJDIR)%.o:$(SRCDIR)%.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ -c $<
...
```

> **Here I call the function.** *The path to my lib is no necessary, only the name*

```c
#include "mylib.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    int a = 3;
    int b = 2;

    printf("my function result: %i", my_function(a, b));
}
```

Exist a difference between this?

*pd: I dont know the version of Dox. Im in my college mac computer, and i know i have some depracated software versions, idk if its the case*

Comment: This is Doxygen and not C question

Comment: Edit: Ok you're right!!  /// Sorry but no, is a c question. I put in the description that i'm using files like 'file.c' and 'lib.h'. This or im not sure what is Doxygen

Comment: The files are C code files, but the documentation system you are using is Doxygen, which is independent from C. You are asking about how doxygen works with the in/out parameter to the @param command. See [here](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdparam).

Comment: No problem. As for your question, this depends on how you process the doxygen comments afterwards. Even if the direction is not shown in VS Code, at the very least, adding the in/out information adds clarification for when someone reads your code.

Comment: It is preferred that rather than linking to pictures, place them directly into the post.  (And when applicable it is better to include text rather than a picture of text.)

Comment: Whe you are using doxygen, which version of doxygen? and I don't see any doxygen comments (`/**` or `/*!`) just plain C comments (`/*`)

Comment: I add some more info to question, thank you

Comment: In a command windows just give `doxygen -v` and you know the version. I don't see any screenshots related to doxygen or is this question about VSCode? VSCode has nothing to do with doxygen.

Comment: Looking at the title of your question "Is there any difference between declaring @param[in] and @param (without [in]) in C libraries" and the given place where `@param` is used, the answer is no as the compiler does not interpret the comments, the comments are used for indicating something to human readers when reading the code or tos show some help in an IDE  or to give information to documentation generators.

Comment: thank you, I think my  Macos (school) didnt have doxygen installed(?) (command not found: doxygen). Oh i see, then the only difference to use [in] near @param is...best practice? or why?